# NumberFormatException in GSON when converting String to double

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am working with a JSON response that is improperly formatted. All fields are being returned as `Strings`. Unfortunately, **I have no control over the return data**.

I am using Gson and attempting to parse a JSON object that includes a field like this:

```
{
        [...]
    "cost": "9.25"
}
```

It should obviously be printed as a `Number`. When I try to parse this as a `String`, `Number` or `double` I get a NumberFormatException:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
        [...]
    at com.myapp.android.LauncherActivity$1.onSuccess(LauncherActivity.java:69)
        [...]
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
    at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:267)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:285)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextInt(JsonReader.java:599)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:228)
    ... 19 more
```

LauncherActivity Line 69:

```
Item item = gson.fromJson(response, Item.class);
```

---

So I followed [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863429/how-to-handle-a-numberformatexception-with-gson-in-deserialization-a-json-respon) and tried creating a `TypeAdapter` like so:

```
public class CostTypeAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<Double>, JsonSerializer<Double> {

    public Double deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Double cost;
        try {
            cost = json.getAsDouble();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            cost = 0.00d;
        }
        return cost;
    }

    public JsonElement serialize(Double src, Type typeOfSrc, 
            JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(src);
    }
}
```

And registered it when creating the `GsonBuilder`:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Cost.class, new CostTypeAdapter());
Gson gson = builder.create();
```

And my `Cost` class:

```
public class Cost {
    private Double value;

    public Cost(Double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Double getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

But I get the same `NumberFormatException`.

Any ideas on whats happening here? Shouldn't this exception be caught in my `CostTypeAdapter.deserialize()`, at the very least?

Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also use `GsonBuilder`'s `registerTypeAdapter()` to catch possible parsing Exceptions and deal with them the way you want.

Example for catching `NumberFormatException` when parsing `Float` and make the value null:

```
    GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
    gb.registerTypeAdapter(Float.class, new TypeAdapter<Float>() {

        @Override
        public Float read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
            if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
                reader.nextNull();
                return null;
            }
            String stringValue = reader.nextString();
            try {
                Float value = Float.valueOf(stringValue);
                return value;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void write(JsonWriter writer, Float value) throws IOException {
            if (value == null) {
                writer.nullValue();
                return;
            }
            writer.value(value);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up having to write a `JsonDeserializer` for my entire enclosing "Item" class.

```
public class ItemDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Item> {

    @Override
    public Item deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type,
            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        JsonObject jobject = (JsonObject) json;

        return new Item(
                    [...],
                (jobject.has("cost")) ? jobject.get("cost").getAsDouble() : 0.00d
                );
    }
}
```

Would still love to see a solution for my original issue, so I wouldn't have to manually parse every field.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `cost` field in your Item class is declared as an `int`, not as a `double`. Changing cost to a `double` should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Paul, I have a similar issue of getting numbers in my JSON that are stored as `String`s. What's been working for me is this:

```
public enum Plan {
        GUEST_PASS, FREE, PREMIUM;

        static Plan fromValue(int value) {
            for (Plan plan : plans)
                if (value == plan.ordinal())
                    return plan;
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value for Plan: " + value);
        }

        static Plan fromValue(String string) {
            try {
                return fromValue(parseInt(string));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException _) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value for Plan: " + string);
            }
        }

        private static EnumSet<Plan> plans = EnumSet.allOf(Plan.class);
    }

public static class PlanAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Plan> {
    @Override public void write(JsonWriter json, Plan plan) throws IOException {
        json.value(Integer.toString(plan.ordinal()));
    }

    @Override public Plan read(JsonReader json) throws IOException {
        return Plan.fromValue(json.nextString());
    }
}
```

Seems like you have continuous data in your case, so you would suffice to have a `class`, I converted to an enum since I had discrete data.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into a similar situation. I used below adaptor for the conversion. I Found it concise.

```
.registerTypeAdapter(Double.class, new JsonSerializer<Double>() {
            public JsonElement serialize(Double number, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
                return new JsonPrimitive(Double.valueOf(number));
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest solution is to make the attribute to be String instead of double and in the get method parse it to double.

for example:

```
class Location {
 private String latitude;
 private String longitude;

 public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude.isEmpty() ? 0d : Double.parseDouble(latitude);
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude.isEmpty() ? 0d : Double.parseDouble(longitude);
    }
}
```