# Convert String into a BigDecimal in Android

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

The data returned from my application API contains the product price stored as a String for example:

```
{
   price:"1500"
}
```

This causes a NumberFormatException because the data type used in the Product model is a BigDecimal. How do I parse this string from the database into a BigDecimal before using it within the application?

I am using Retrofit and GSON, and have tried the solutions here:

[NumberFormatException in GSON when converting String to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239117/numberformatexception-in-gson-when-converting-string-to-double)

**Solution 1:**

```
GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
    gb.registerTypeAdapter(Float.class, new TypeAdapter<Float>() {

        @Override
        public Float read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
            if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
                reader.nextNull();
                return null;
            }
            String stringValue = reader.nextString();
            try {
                Float value = Float.valueOf(stringValue);
                return value;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void write(JsonWriter writer, Float value) throws IOException {
            if (value == null) {
                writer.nullValue();
                return;
            }
            writer.value(value);
        }

    });
```

This solution seems correct but I failed to return the parsed value when the exception occurs, instead of returning null.

**Solution 2:**

```
.registerTypeAdapter(Double.class, new JsonSerializer<Double>() {
            public JsonElement serialize(Double number, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
                return new JsonPrimitive(Double.valueOf(number));
            }
        })
```

For this solution, BigDecimal isn't a supported JsonPrimitive datatype.

Comment: _How do I parse this string from the database into a BigDecimal before using it within the application?_ 
you just store it in a string and parse it as BigDecimal

Comment: I understand how to do this. My question is how to use this to parse a json string into a big decimal.

Comment: Are you sure you are not trying to parse the json string? Log the string before you parse so that you can u can understand what is being parsed

Comment: The price is a string. My question is how to parse it into a big decimal using either a type adapter or a json serializer

Answer (score 0):

> It's working fine for me
>
> ```
> String total=“1500.00”;
>
> BigDecimal sPrice = new BigDecimal(total);
> ```

Comment: How do I use this to parse JSON data? The string from the databse is causing a NumberFormatEXception.

Comment: which database mysql or sqlite ?

Comment: the database is sql and the data is returned from an api

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
gb.registerTypeAdapter(String.class, new TypeAdapter<String>() {

    @Override
    public String read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            reader.nextNull();
            return null;
        }
        String stringValue = reader.nextString();
        try {
            BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(stringValue);
            globalVariable = value;  //globalVariable must be of type BigDecimal OR provide some callback mechanism here
            return stringValue;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter writer, Float value) throws IOException {
        if (value == null) {
            writer.nullValue();
            return;
        }
        writer.value(value);
    }

});
```

Comment: You cannot return a big decimal where you declared a type adapter for a string