# Gson parse error, when the server response data is include an empty string(intent to be a int type), the error is Invalid double: ""

Tags: json, gson

the server response data is like as

```
{
  ...
  "number":"",
  ...
}
```

so when i use

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.fromJson(data, obj.class);
```

the error will appear seems the String is null.
I've serach it with google and it seems custom GsonBuilder will solve this problem, but is it really and how?

Comment: `""` is not null. It's an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, beacause the comment's hint, i changed my Google search wrods,and find this problem[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863429/how-to-handle-a-numberformatexception-with-gson-in-deserialization-a-json-respon)

This link will solve my problem.

So i write a primitive type typeadapter,and finally it works.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, in place of "Object" use object of the class you need to convert to.

Type type= new TypeToken< Object>(){}.getType();

Object obj=new Gson().fromJson(json,type);